# How can I get youtube channel id by auto-generated channel #name?

Tags: youtube-api, auto-generate, youtube-channels

I'm trying to retrieve a youtube auto-generated channel's video by youtube channel name like #ComputerScience. I searched around and couldn't figure out a way of how to do it, once the channel doesn't have an user. Any suggestion of how do it?

My code works fine for user generated content but for auto-generated doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way looks fine

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=%23computerscience&key={YOUR_API_KEY}